# Mail Not being delivered to gmail

Tags: gmail, php

I am using PHP mail function to send mail, Its getting delivered to all other mail servers but not gmail.

Here is my headers

```
$headers = "From: Somename<sales@domain.net>\r\n";  
$headers .= "Reply-To: sales@domain.net\r\n".
$headers .="Return-Path: sales@domain.net\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .='X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Hi, this has many duplicates already in the "related" column.

Comment: GMail is probably detecting it as spam, especially if you're on a shared hosting provider.

Comment: Does your server / PHP installation support the use of mail() function? Also, did you check spam/junk etc?

Comment: Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: You may have to check if the mail is in the SPAM box

Comment: @AmalMurali yes mail function is supported
I can send mail to all other server like yahoo,hotmail even webmail

Comment: @chrislondon,Kim Tan Yes i checked the spam folder nothing there.

Comment: are you using the right `SMTP` for `Gmail` and making sure you are using ssl and the right port for it

Comment: @AlmoullimDev. 
Just need to ask you is ssl a compulsary requirement to send email to to gmail account using php mail function.

Comment: @tousif as far as i know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: sales@domain.net\r\n".
```

in your headers instead of

```
$headers .= "Reply-To: sales@domain.net\r\n";
```

You mistyped '.' instead of ';', that's why its causing error.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i see you are not given the rest of the code so i can see whats wrong
so i will post you the code im using with gmail to send email

Code :

```
    $sendmail = require_once('../lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
include("../lib/phpmailer/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body = " Body Msg ";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "mail@gmail.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "pass";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('$qemail', 'first name');

$mail->Subject    = "hi name";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "mail@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "first name");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

if you are welling to try the code don't forget to set the right place for the classes in the include function and the require_once

Comment: ok will try that.Thanks
Yeah I have used php mailer class before

Comment: +1 for your effort
Though my problem was solved
removing $headers .="Return-Path: sales@domain.net\r\n".
fom headers